# How to implement pointers in Python? (or any similar solution else)

Tags: python, pointers

I have a Class, it will be implemented to be many instances. I want to keep connections between some of the instances, and pass messages among them. In C++, I can do this like:

```
class A
{
   A (*connections)[];
   int sum;

public:
   void pass(int index)
   {
       connections[index] -> receive(sum);
   }
   void receive(int input)
   {
       sum += input;
   }
}
```

Then **I only need to add pointers** of other instances to `connections[]`, I can pass messages among them with each other.

Currently I have to use Python doing this, **but Python doesn't support pointers**. I wonder what is the proper solution, or design pattern, to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't quite follow your C++ code, could you provide a Python usage example?

Comment: @RikPoggi , I don't know how to implement this in Python, that's why I ask here...

Comment: I wasn't looking for the class `A` implementation, but for the API of its instances.

Comment: `connections[index] -> receive(sum);` is similar to `connections[index].receive(sum)` in Python, but `connections[index]` should be a pointer (or say a reference, not a value).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python doesn't need pointers in order to achieve this as every variable is a reference to an object.  These references are slightly different from C++ references, in that they can be assigned to - much like pointers in C++.

So to achieve what you're looking for, you'd just need to do something like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__( self, connections, sum ):
        self.connections = connections
        self.sum = sum

    def passToConnections( self, index ):
        self.connections[ index ].receive( self.sum )

    def receive( self, input ):
       self.sum += input
```

And just to prove that this works as expected:

```
>>> a1 = A( [], 0 )
>>> a2 = A( [], 0 )
>>> a3 = A( [ a1, a2 ], 10 )
>>> a3.passToConnections( 0 )
>>> a3.passToConnections( 1 )
>>> a3.passToConnections( 1 )
>>> print a1.sum
10
>>> print a2.sum
20
```

So as you can see we have altered the original objects `a1` and `a2` by calling through to them via the references in `a3`

Comment: @obmag: The pass method should pass `self.sum` into the call to `receive`.  but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 4):

In Python we have *names* and *containers* (such as `list`) that refer to objects, similar to *references* in C++. Example -- a and b refer to the same object:

```
>>> a = object()
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
```

Comment: In which way is your answer answering the OP question?

Comment: That any variable is just a pointer. So when you save "object" somewhere it is just saving its pointer.

Comment: @rplnt: And now that OP knows this (which he also seemed to [already know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821607/how-to-implement-pointers-in-python-or-any-similar-solution-else#comment12512310_9821607)) how would his problem be solved? IMO this is a very poor answer, without even a link to the doc or some in-depth explanation.

Comment: Explanation is often better than complete solution I guess. And `connections[index]` is not a value, it's a reference. When you change it, referenced object changes. Except the case when it is immutable (such as Number or str).

Comment: @rplnt: Nothing that you just said is in this answer, you're making my point that it's a poor answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you might be looking for a [class attribute](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

Would something like this work for you?

```
class A(object):
    connection = []
    def send(self, num):
        self.connection.append(num)
    def receive(self):
        return self.connection.pop(-1)
```

Example:

```
>>> x = A()
>>> y = A()
>>> x.send(10)
>>> y.receive()
10
```

Anyway you might want to implement this with the [`queue`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/queue.html) module.

**Edit:** I'd guess that you want the `receive` method to look like:

```
def receive(self):
    s = sum(self.connection)
    self.connection[:] = []    # empty the list
    return s
```

Beware that you should never assign anything to the `connection` attribute or you'll loose the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Python standard way of handling things supports you.  In python every variable is a reference.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, name, lsum):
        self.__name = name
        self.__sum = lsum
        self.__connections = []

    def add_connection(self, con):
        self.__connections.append(con)

    def send_signal(self, cidx):
        print("Send signal from [%s] to [%s]" % 
              (self.__name, self.__connections[cidx].__name))
        self.__connections[cidx].receive(self.__sum)

    def receive(self, lsum):
        print("Add [%s] to [%s] in [%s]" % (lsum, self.__sum, self.__name))
        self.__sum += lsum

    def get_sum(self):
        return self.__sum

a = A("Obj1", 10)
b = A("Obj2", 20)
c = A("Obj3", 30)

a.add_connection(b)
a.add_connection(c)

a.send_signal(0)
a.send_signal(1)

print("Sum A [%s]" % a.get_sum())
print("Sum B [%s]" % b.get_sum())
print("Sum C [%s]" % c.get_sum())
```

Output:

```
Send signal from [Obj1] to [Obj2]
Add [10] to [20] in [Obj2]
Send signal from [Obj1] to [Obj3]
Add [10] to [30] in [Obj3]
Sum A [10]
Sum B [30]
Sum C [40]
```