# Explanation about pointers vs manipulating objects in a linked list

Tags: python, object, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the concept of switching pointers vs actual manipulation of objects in a linked list.

Here is the code for building the linked list from scratch

```
class ListNode:

    def __init__(self, val:int, nextNode=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = nextNode

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self, val=None):

        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def addValue(self, val:int):
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = self.tail = ListNode(val)

        else:
            self.tail.next = ListNode(val)
            self.tail = self.tail.next
        return self.tail

    def addMultiple(self, values:list):

        for i in values:
            self.addValue(i)


    def add_to_beginning(self, val):
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = self.tail = ListNode(val)
        else:
            self.head = ListNode(val, self.head)

    def display(self):

        elems = []

        curr = self.head
        while curr:
            elems.append(curr.val)
            curr = curr.next

        print(elems)
```

creating a linked list here:

```
l1 = LinkedList()
l1.addMultiple([1,2,3,4,5])
```

For example if I wanted to move the nth element to the head, so I created this function

```
class Solution:

    def move_n_to_head(self, head, n):

        if head == None:
            return None
        if head.next == None:
            return head

        temp = None
        count = 0
        dummy = fast = slow = ListNode(0)

        fast.next = head
        while fast:

            if count == n:
                temp = fast.next
                fast.next = fast.next.next #why does this line manipuate the head?
                break

            fast = fast.next #why does this line NOT manipulate the head?
            count += 1

        slow.next = temp
        slow.next.next = head
        return dummy.next
```

Everything works fine and I got the solution I wanted, but specifically I don't understand why this line **does** manipulate the head?

```
fast.next = fast.next.next
```

After using this above line in the 3rd iteration, the head now becomes [1,2,3,5]

However while this line **does not** manipulates the head as I am traversing through the list? The head remains [1,2,3,4,5] after every iteration?

```
fast = fast.next
```

I read this other stackoverflow explanation on dummy node pointers which was helpful but I still don't understand it.

[Explanation about dummy nodes and pointers in linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58715870/explanation-about-dummy-nodes-and-pointers-in-linked-lists)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is good to see such a clear and easy to read code. Now, the reason why the following line doesn't work

```py
fast.next = head #fast is an object.
```

is because you are declaring fast as an object

```py
dummy = fast = slow = ListNode(0) #just here
```

#### What happens?

In python you are working with objects rather than pointers (and pointers really aren't that, they are references.

Sometimes some variables passed or created are interpreted as objects and sometimes as pointers (references).

Well, you will see:

> Python doesn't need pointers in order to achieve this as every variable is a reference to an object. These references are slightly different from C++ references, in that they can be assigned to - much like pointers in C++. ([obmarg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589746/obmarg))

It is quite hard to tell you how to make the lenaguage interpret variables as object references.

If I think about it well, it may be done in this case with the following modification

```py
class Solution:

    def move_n_to_head(self, head, n):

        if head == None:
            return None
        if head.next == None:
            return head

        temp = None
        count = 0
        dummy = slow = ListNode(0)

        fast = head #fast now "points" to head 
        # (it depends if it is taken as a copy of head or a reference to it)
        while fast:

            if count == n:
                temp = fast.next
                fast.next = fast.next.next #It should be solved
                break

            fast = fast.next
            count += 1

        slow.next = temp
        slow.next.next = head
        return dummy.next
```

#### Note:

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821607/how-to-implement-pointers-in-python-or-any-similar-solution-else) discusses how to implement pointers in python, and may give you more information about how to handle them.

I really hope it helps you, thanks for reading this answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this!

I still don't understand why fast = fast.next DOES NOT manipulate the head while fast.next = fast.next.next DOES manipulate the head. I have edit my question above with an example. Thanks!